# Compute module 3 ttyAMA0

Tags: raspbian, serial, rpi.gpio, compute-module-3

just got my hands on the new CM3, flashed a fresh raspbian image on it and noticed ttyAMA0 is not there (it has been used for bluetooth since raspberry pi 3). the only way to get it back is to change `/boot/config.txt` and append the option `dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt` and run `systemctl disable hciuart`. this will get you ttyAMA0 on rpi3 but it just doesn't work on the CM3.
is there something more i need to do ? can it be because the CM3 doesn't have Bluetooth and somehow needs some patch or something ?

PS: i really need that serial port and the mini-uart doesn't work for me.

Comment: ttyAMA0 is an arbitrary name. Is it possible they use a different name?

Comment: nope it's disabled

Comment: The reason I asked is the name is different in some of the GPS tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add

dtparam=uart0=on

to config.txt

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=141248&p=1100536

Answer (score 1):

[image: serial0 is link to ttyAMA0]

In Raspbian Jessie (Lite) /dev/serial0 is a symlink to /dev/ttyAMA0. Serial0 now used in /boot/cmdline.txt